# Encrypting network traffic with Java and RSA

Tags: java, rsa, encryption

I'm wondering how I should approach a homework assignment.

I must develop a simple server and client in Java, which I have done.  Next, I must encrypt the traffic between this server and client by using RSA with the following given keys.

```
Client Public Key: (5, 10142789312725007)
Client Private Key: (8114231289041741, 10142789312725007)
Server Public Key: (5, 10142701089716483)
Server Private Key: (6085620532976717, 10142701089716483)
```

Does Java have built-in functionality that will allow me to do this easily?

Thanks!

Comment: That depends on what the assigment asks you to do now, doesn't it? Can you post a linkt to the assignment?

Comment: It sounds to me like you need to implement the RSA algorithm.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I was hoping someone might know of a way around that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Java has [built-in support for RSA](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html) that would let you do this easily.

It also has support for arbitrary-precision integers, [including a `modPow` operation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#modPow%28java.math.BigInteger,%20java.math.BigInteger%29) that make it pretty easy for you to implement RSA encryption yourself.

Honestly, simply implementing RSA using `BigInteger` is probably easier than learning enough about the Java Cryptography Architecture to use the built-in RSA implementation.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some links that might help:

[A Java implementation of RSA](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/rsa/implementation.html)

[Java Class - RSA Implementation](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/introcs/78crypto/RSA.java.html)

> Generate an N-bit public and private
>   RSA key and use to encrypt and decrypt
>   a random message.

[Using RSA encryption with Java - tutorial](http://www.aviransplace.com/2004/10/12/using-rsa-encryption-with-java/)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the Java Cryptographic Extension that comes with Java.

For making the given numbers an RSA key convert them to [BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) and "feed" them into a [RSAPrivateKeySpec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/spec/RSAPrivateKeySpec.html) resp. [RSAPublicKeySpec](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/spec/RSAPublicKeySpec.html). 
Using a [KeyFactory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/security/KeyFactory.html) you can then make the *Spec to regular Public and private keys that can be used with all cryptographic functions within Java.